# Unable to update/modify SwiftUI View's @state var

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13

I'm unable to update the ExampleView's `message` var even though I can see `updateMessage()` is being called. Here is my simplified/convoluted SwiftUI example of Playground code that isn't working. The `message` var does not get updated when called in `updateMessage()`. As a result, the UI `Text()` is not updated either.

Why is the @State var `message` not updating? What is the correct way to update it?

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    let coloredLabel = ExampleView()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            coloredLabel
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .padding()
            Button(action: {
                self.coloredLabel.updateMessage()
            }) {
                Text("Press me")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var message: String = "Hello"

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.message)
    }

    func updateMessage() {
        print("updateMessage ran") // this prints
        self.message = "Updated"
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: You can only set a view's `State` inside its own `body` block. You are setting `ExampleView`'s state in `ContentView.body`, which is not allowed. I _think_ this is where you should use a `@Binding`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should only change `State` of a view **inside** its own body block. If you need to change it from a parent view, you may want to pass the value to it from parent and make it `Binding` instead.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var message = "Hello"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ExampleView(message: $message)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .padding()
            Button("Press me") {
                self.message = "Updated"
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    @Binding var message: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(message)
    }
}
```

---

If you need to encapsulate messages inside the `ExampleView`, you can use a `Bool` (or an `enum` or etc) instead:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var updated = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ExampleView(isUpdated: $updated)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .padding()
            Button("Press me") {
                self.updated = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    @Binding var isUpdated: Bool
    private var message: String { isUpdated ? "Updated" : "Hello" }

    var body: some View {
        Text(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you limited to Bool or enum? I'd like to use Int, or in the example String

Comment: No, you can use anything fits your case. The point is to trigger the change with a `binding` variable from parent.

Comment: Ok, I got it working using the binding example. One gotcha I ran into was using `Text(self.message)` in the View body. That doesn't work. It has to be `Text(message)`. Thanks!

Comment: Whats the reason we should only @State when changing the value inside body block?

Comment: Who said that? 

Answer (score 13):

actually, the variable does get updated, but your Content view doesn't get informed about it. This is what happens:

- ContentView gets called, it initializes *coloredLabel* with an *ExampleView*
- you press the button in ContentView
- self.coloredLabel.updateMessage() get's called
- the message is printed
- the variable self.coloredLabel.message is modified
- ContentView does not get redrawn, as it isn't notified about the change
- more specifically, *coloredLabel* inside your Stack doesn't get updated

now, you have different options:
`@State`, `@Binding` and `@PublishedObject, @ObservedObject`. You need one of these Publishers, so your view actually notices that it needs to do something.

Either you draw a new `ExampleView` every time you press the button, in this case you can use a `@State` variable in `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var string = "Hello"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ExampleView(message: string)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .padding()
            Button(action: {
                self.string = "Updated"
            }) {
                Text("Press me")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    var message: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.message)
    }
}
```

which is probably not what you want.

Next, you can use *@Binding* which was already suggested.

And last, you can use *ObservableObject @ObservedObject, @Published*

```
class ExampleState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var message: String = "Hello"
    func update() {
        message = "Updated"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var state = ExampleState()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ExampleView(state: state)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .padding()
            Button(action: {
                self.state.update()
            }) {
                Text("Press me")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var state: ExampleState

    var body: some View {
        Text(state.message)
    }
}
```

what this says is:
`class ExampleState: ObservableObject` - this class has published variables that can be observed

to resume (that's how I understand it):

- "Hey, `ContentView` and `ExampleView`: if `state.message` (any value that `state` publishes) changes, you need to redraw your body"
- "And `ExampleState`: after updating your message variable, publish the new value!"

lastly - for completion - there is `@EnvironmentObject`, as well, that way you'd only have to pass the variable to the top-views and everything down the view hierarchy would inherit it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions that should work, but as guys say, you can work with `@Binding`

```
 struct ExampleView: View {

        var message: String = "Hello"

        var body: some View {
            Text(self.message)
        }

        mutating func updateMessage() {
            print("updateMessage ran")
            message = "Updated"
        }
    }
```