# Swift. Randomise the index selected of an array of images

Tags: arrays

so what i am trying to do is create a game where random images are shown on screen and you must select the correct one. Six random tappable images(targets) are displayed from an array of 180 and a seventh image(main target) which indicates which image you must tap. What i can't achieve is displaying the seventh image which must randomly display one of the other six images on screen. I have tried a few things but i can never get it to choose a different one randomly. My current code wont even display the seventh image. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have searched to see if this question has been answered before but it either hasn't or i'm too stupid to know what i'm looking at(yet) which is more likely. Thanks in advance!

I wont include the whole array.

```
@State private var targetArray = ["Target1", "Target2", "Target3", "Target4", "Target5", "Target6", "Target7", "Target8", "Target9", "Target10"]
 @State private var MainTarget = Int.random(in: 0...5)
    @State private var numbers = Array(0...6)
    @State private var score = 0

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Image("Background")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 135/255, green: 130/255, blue: 100/255)).cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding(.top, 55)
                    .padding(.bottom, 530)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 25)
            }

            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    //TODO: add button
                    Text("X")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Score:")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .bold()
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .padding(.all, 10)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(String(score))
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .padding(.all, 10)
                    Spacer()
                }

                Text("TARGET")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .bold()
                    .padding([.leading,
                    .trailing], 5)

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(String(self.MainTarget))
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                        .padding(15)
                    Spacer()
                }

                Spacer()

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                     //button1
                    Button(action: {
                        self.numbers = self.numbers.map({ _ in
                        Int.random(in: 0...self.targetArray.count - 1)
                        })
                        if self.MainTarget == self.numbers[0] {
                            self.score += 1

                        }
                        else if self.MainTarget != self.numbers[0] {
                            self.score -= 1
                            //TODO: add game over
                        }
                    }) {
                        TargetView(targetArray: $targetArray[numbers[0]])
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This was done without testing)

Hey! Pretty sure your issue lays in the fact that you're attempting to render `self.MainTarget` as if it were an image when in reality it is just an randomized integer. Try replacing

```
Image(String(self.MainTarget))
   .renderingMode(.original)
   .resizable()
   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
   .cornerRadius(20)
   .padding(15)
```

with

```
Image(self.targetArray[self.MainTarget])
   .renderingMode(.original)
   .resizable()
   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
   .cornerRadius(20)
   .padding(15)
```

Comment: That now shows the image, any ideas on how to make it randomly select from one of the others?

Comment: You should be able to just reset `self.MainTarget = Int.random(in: 0...5)` and then rerender.

Comment: When i open it in the simulator it does choose from one of the six but wont randomise between them when i tap on  the correct one. Honestly thanks for all you're help so far Jack!

Comment: So you're going to want to look into a view press handler. Not sure which framework you're using. In the press handler add the `self.MainTarget = Int.random(in: 0...5)`. My pleasure! I remember all the help I got, just trying to pass it along.

Comment: Ah my bad, I haven't worked with Swift UI before and was just glancing at your code. Firstly, you're probably going to want a View setup like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59783801/3788614) to manage your variable states so that the views dynamically update when their image changes. Then, in your Button press update the variable as I showed before. By the way, for reference, a press handler is used in Cocoa to capture the press event and run a function.

Comment: Thank you Jack, that is extremely helpful!

Comment: My pleasure once again! If you don’t mind, please mark my answer as correct for others who check the post.