# SwiftUI list item not updated if model is wrapped in @State

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, declarative-programming

Given

- a View with a simple List
- an ItemView for each element of the list
- a Model for the app
- a model value (Deck)

Tapping on a button in the main view, is expected the model to change and propagate the changes to the ItemView.

**The problem** is that the changes only propagate if the model struct is stored in the ItemView as a normal variable; but if i add the `@State` property wrapper these do not happen. The view will update but not change (like if the data has been cached).

**Question 1:** is this an expected behaviour? If so, why? I was expecting to have the ItemView to only update when the model change by observing it throw @State, this way instead the view will always refresh whenever the list commands it, even if the data is not updated?

**Question 2:** Is it normal otherwise to have the items of a list using plain structs properties as models? Using observable classes would create much more complexity when handling the array in the view model and also make more complicated the List refreshing/identifying mechanism seems to me.

In the example the model does not need the @State, since changes are only coming from outside, in real world i would need it when it's the view itself to trigger the changes?

This is a stripped down version to reproduce the issue (create a project and replace ContentView with following):

```
import SwiftUI

struct Deck: Identifiable {

    let id: Int
    var name: String

    init(_ name: String, _ id: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    // @State var deck: Deck  // DOES NOT WORK !!! <-------------------
    let deck: Deck             // WORKS (first element is updated)

    var body: some View { Text(deck.name) }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {

    @Published var decks: [Deck] = getData()

    static func getData(changed: Bool = false) -> [Deck] {
        let firstElement = changed ? "CHANGED ELEMENT" : "0"
        return [Deck(firstElement, 0), Deck("1", 1), Deck("2", 2)]
    }

    func changeFirst() { self.decks = Self.getData(changed: true) }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(model.decks) { deck in
                ItemView(deck: deck)
            }
            Button(action: model.changeFirst) {
                Text("Change first item")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Tested with Xcode 13 / iPhone13 Simulator (iOS 15)*

Comment: State and Published are a source of truth, Binding is a two way connection. State would break the connection with the previous source of truth by making a copy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update/modify SwiftUI View's @state var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59783686/unable-to-update-modify-swiftui-views-state-var)   It says, 
`You should only change State of a view inside its own body block. If you need to change it from a parent view, you may want to pass the value to it from parent and make it Binding instead.`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thanks, but i don't change the state of the view, it's a struct, whenever it is updated it is actually a new instance (both of the View and the model with the same `id`). If i am understanding correctly. I can't make it binding either, it's an array, and the elements change position, state, etc.

Comment: @loremipsum thanks, i see it now i think. The more i use List the less i like it then

Comment: If you put down a simplpe answer to the two questions with what's in the comments i accept it right off

Comment: `...in real world i would need it when it's the view itself to trigger the changes?`
 
 works very well if you use a `Binding`, that would cater for your "real world" code.

Comment: This is SwiftUI 101, watch Demystify SwiftUI from one of the WWDCs it is very informative you can make Bindings easily by adding a `$`, `ForEach($vm.decks, id: \.id) { $deck in`

Comment: Oh ok i must have missed this (just learning swiftui) thanks a lot

Comment: @malhal i appreciate the intention, but i feel your changes to my question's code are opinionated (i read mvvm resentment maybe?) and have changed the meaning of the code, especially removing the \.id and Protocols requirements part will radically change the meaning of the posted code (which may or may not be correct, does not matter). You should avoid doing this. The code is obviously a reduction and most lines are there to represent something. I you feel my code was wrong, you should write an answer, and i would warmly appreciate that, but changing the question really does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**
Yes, it is expected because `@State` and `@Published` are sources of truth. `@State` breaks the connection with `@Published` and makes a copy.

**Question 2**
If all the changes are outside (one-way connection) you don't need wrappers of any kind for the children when dealing with value types.

If you need a two-way connection you use `@Binding` when dealing with a `struct`/value type.

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app