# How to modify state inside a func in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want to modify my state inside a function but xcode gave this error:

> Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var offsetEnum: OffsetEnum = .left
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            MyView(offsetEnum: offsetEnum)
            
            Button("update") {
                if offsetEnum == .left {
                    offsetEnum = .right
                }
                else {
                    offsetEnum = .left
                }
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct MyView: View {
    
    let offsetEnum: OffsetEnum
    @State private var angle: Angle = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .rotationEffect(angle)
            .offset(offsetCalculator())
        
    }
    
    func offsetCalculator() -> CGSize {
        
        switch offsetEnum {
        case .left:
            angle -= Angle(degrees: 45.0)
            return CGSize(width: -200.0, height: .zero)
        case .right:
            angle += Angle(degrees: 45.0)
            return CGSize(width: 200.0, height: .zero)
        }
        
    }
    
}

enum OffsetEnum {
    case left, right
}
```

As you can see the offset can be left or right but even if we are in same posation I want be able update the angle via pressing the button. How to solve this issue?

Comment: This is rather odd, you're doing your updating inside `offsetCalculator()`, which is triggered on every render (and not when the button is pressed). That `offsetCalculator()` also always returns the same two offset `CGSize` values, which is also odd in itself. Could you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achieve? Why not trigger the angle change from the update button?

Comment: Let me explain my issue in this way, I want angle get added or removed the value of Angle(degrees: 45.0) always, I am not looking to use onChange or any similar modifier. The goal of the question is about to update state wrapper not in direct way because I want keep it private so I thought I could update the state via offsetEnum. But I think I touched the limitation of SwiftUI, and I should not code like that.

Comment: "I want angle get added or removed ... always", what _exactly_ do you mean by "always"? From what I see, you're trying to get a button in a parent view (`ContentView`) to trigger changes in a child view (`MyView`). The way to do that in SwiftUI is to have your child view take a `Binding` for its angle. The button in the parent just sets the angle, and the child view automatically react to those changes.

Comment: That is also fine for me, but as you said if we use Binding there, then we need to modify angle itself then send modified value of angle to child, so doing that in child view or in parent view does not change the question, right? the point is that angle get midfield.

Comment: " so doing that in child view or in parent view does not change the question, right? the point is that angle get midfield." I didn't understand any of this part, coudl you please elaborate? Is `midfield` a typo?

Comment: you know we have toggle in bool which is imbedded to the Bool value itself when we use toggle on a state we actually doing the same thing that I am trying to do with angle. I hope I cloud say what I am trying to do. Maybe I should extend Angle itself rather than trying solve the issue in a view itself. Or not, I think the result would be the same.

Comment: "you know we have toggle in bool which is imbedded to the Bool value itself" Are you referring to [`Bool.toggle()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bool/toggle())? What about it? It just edits a boolean value in-place. "when we use toggle on a state we actually doing the same thing that I am trying to do with angle." So you're trying to edit an `Angle` value in-place. Isn't that what `-=` and `+=` are already doing? What's the issue exactly? I think there's a bit of a communication barrier here

Comment: I thought doing -= and += in lower level code help rather than doing it in view itself.

Comment: You can extract out your logic into an `ObservableObject`, and then put a `@StateObject` in your parent view to create/retain it. SwiftUI is not top-down commands like UIKit was. When you have a piece of state that's shared by some subtree of views, the parent of that subtree usually owns it, and hands it down to children who care about it. That parent can either pass down bindings, or pass a reference to a whole `ObservableObject`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418859/3141234

Comment: "Declare state as private in the highest view in the view hierarchy that needs access to the value. Then share the state with any subviews that also need access, either directly for read-only access, or as a binding for read-write access." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/State

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution, which moves the state into the parent view:

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    enum OffsetEnum { case left, right }

    @State private var offsetEnum: OffsetEnum = .left
    @State private var angle: Angle = .zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChildView(angle: angle)
            Button("update") {
                if offsetEnum == .left {
                    angle -= Angle(degrees: 45.0)
                    offsetEnum = .right
                }
                else {
                    angle += Angle(degrees: 45.0)
                    offsetEnum = .left
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    public let angle: Angle

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .rotationEffect(angle)
    }
}
```